# Databricks writing to Synapse changes datatype for created Synapse table columns

Tags: databricks, azure-synapse

I have Synapse table created with column datatype - `[Comments] [varchar](2000) NULL`

When I write to Synapse using Databricks spark code, I see data type of Synapse table column change to `[Comments] [nvarchar](256) NULL`. I have data type as string on Databricks dataframe.

Databricks Spark code-

```
df.write \
      .format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw") \
      .option("url",  "jdbc:sqlserver://<>") \
      .option("user", "myuser") \
      .option("password", "***") \
      .option("forwardSparkAzureStorageCredentials", "true") \
      .option("dbTable", table_name) \
      .option("tempDir", "wasbs://<container>@<storageAccount>.blob.core.windows.net/<path>) \
      .mode("overwrite")  \
      .save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would either add the following [option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/synapse-analytics#parameters) to your code:

```py
.option("maxStrLength", 2000)
```

Or if you are sure the column names and data types won’t change over time, I would manually drop and create the table with the types you want, then change mode to “append” and then add a pre-action to truncate the table:

```py
.option("preActions", "truncate table "+table_name) \
.mode("append") \
```

Comment: yes it worked with above option

Comment: I was thinking that workaround with "preActions" should not work, because based on docs it works only for new table


"tableOptions, preActions, postActions, and maxStrLength are relevant only when writing data from Azure Databricks to a new table in Azure Synapse."